# Firefox extension Manifest v3 - request permission to "access your data for all websites" at runtime

Tags: permissions, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, manifest.json

Can a Manifest v3 Firefox extension request the `"Access your data for all websites"` permission from the user **at runtime**?

This option is usually managed in the firefox `about:addons` built-in page:

[image: Firefox about:addons page]

Some features of my extension require this permission to work, and I want to prompt the user to grant it if it hasn't been granted yet.

The desired workflow is as follows:

When the user clicks a button to trigger a feature that requires this permission, the extension checks if it has the permission to access data for all websites.

If the permission has not been granted yet, the extension should request it from the user. If the permission has already been granted, the feature should be triggered.

I have tried using the [`browser.permissions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/permissions) API, but I could not find a way to request this specific permission at runtime.

Is there any other way to request this permission from the user at runtime, or is it simply not possible?

**Edit:**

Not sure if this is the intended behavior, but sending a permission request with only "origins" and no "permission" key specified seems to work:

```
browser.permissions.request({origins: ['<all_urls>']})
```

Comment: In Chrome you can use chrome.permissions + optional_host_permissions (not host_permissions). Apparently Firefox hasn't implemented it yet.

Comment: Thank you. It appears that this permission is not present in the list of permissions supported by Firefox. However, I might have found a workaround. I tried sending a request for origins: "<all_urls>" with no "permission" key specified and it seems to work. I'll edit my question with the code. I am not sure if this is a bug or intended behavior though

Comment: Did you put this code in background file inside `chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(...` ?

Comment: Never mind! I was able to fire it from content script and It MUST be triggered from a 'call to action' button. So onInstall I open my welcome page to the user and open a permission modal with an 'Accept' button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution

Sending a permission request with the "origins" parameter set to `"<all_urls>"` is equivalent to requesting the "Access your data for all websites" permission:

```
browser.permissions.request({origins: ['<all_urls>']})
```

## Why does it work?

The [MDN Permissions documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/permissions/Permissions) states that both `origins` and `permissions` parameters are optional.

By setting `origins: <all_urls>`, the extension is effectively requesting permission to "Access your data for all websites".

The presence of this permission can be checked by invoking `browser.permissions.getAll()` and checking the presence of `<all_urls>` in `permissions.origins`.

Implementation example:

```
const hasAllUrlsPermission = () => {
    return browser.permissions.getAll()
        .then(permissions => permissions.origins.indexOf("<all_urls>") > - 1);
}
```

## Compatibility

This solution was tested on Firefox v.112.

## About <all_urls>

Granting the `<all_urls>` permission in a Firefox extension can pose a risk to security and privacy.

For this reason, [Mozilla Extension Workshop](https://extensionworkshop.com/documentation/develop/request-the-right-permissions/) recommends to

> Avoid host permission `<all_urls>` if you can.

Where possible and applicable, their recommandation is to

> Use `activeTab` rather than `tabs` and host permissions

Answer (score -1):

Use **'manifest_version'** as **2** instead of 3 in your **manifest.json** file. Using V2 is still considered acceptable and now it should work.

When you download an add-on on Firefox, you will, now, encounter a prompt requesting permission to "**Access all data for all websites**."

Here is a screen capture of solving the problem:

[image: Access your data for all websites, prompt.]

Comment: Yes, but it is not best practice. If you have a manifest v3 extension that work on different browsers, downgrading the version will cause compatibility problems.